# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id

Tags: apex, upsert

I am trying to upsert the list below:

> OpportunityLineItem:{   Id=00k11000007NorcAAC,
>   ServiceDate=2014-03-30 00:00:00,   UnitPrice=200,   Quantity=1,
>   ProposalID__c=1,   Status__c=IN_APPROVAL,
>   ContractPDFLink__c=contractLink,   MISContractReference__c=1,
>   MISOfferID__c=2 }, OpportunityLineItem:{   Id=00k11000007NordAAC,
>   ServiceDate=2014-03-30 00:00:00,   UnitPrice=200,   Quantity=1,
>   ProposalID__c=2,   Status__c=IN_APPROVAL,
>   ContractPDFLink__c=contractLink,   MISContractReference__c=1,
>   MISOfferID__c=2 }

**Code:**

```
if (oppLineItemToUpsert.size() > 0) sr1 = Database.upsert(oppLineItemToUpsert, false);
```

**Result:**

> I am getting the error "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross
>   reference id"

**Log:**

> VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[629]|sr1|[null: invalid cross reference id,null:
>   invalid cross reference id]|0x7db56b63

Comment: Moving this conversation [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55127/discussion-on-question-by-melisha-invalid-cross-reference-key-invalid-cross-ref) as it is long and growing.